# Rotating svg elements about their center

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG image, in which there are individual circles that I want to rotate about their own center (the center of the circles). However when I set `transform-origin:center`, and then apply a transform, it starts rotating about the center of the whole SVG image. Is there any way to set the transform origin such that the circles rotate about their own center?

Here is the original svg image (I cannot paste the original code here so this): [SVG image](https://swachhcoin.com/media/token%20economy.svg)

Here is a jsfiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/g9zfcdm3/3/

There are 4 circles in the image. Achieving this with any one cirlce would be good enough. What I actually want to achieve is to animate these circles so that they rotate indefinitely around their own center.

Comment: Just packed this into a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem and let developers play around and find a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/g9zfcdm3/3/

Comment: Thank you so much. I will post this in the question itself

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See this (resolved as invalid) bug report in Firefox about your problem: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209061

Normally, CSS transforms on SVG elements are relative to the viewport and not to the element itself. This can be changed by adding `transform-box: fill-box`:

```
svg .rotate {
  animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g9zfcdm3/10/

### Background

From the [MDN docs about `transform-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box):

> The transform-box CSS property defines the layout box to which the transform and transform-origin properties relate.
>
> **border-box** (default)
>
> The border box is used as the reference box. The reference box of a  is the border box of its table wrapper box, not its table box.
>
> **fill-box**
>
> The object bounding box is used as the reference box.

Note that it's an experimental feature and probably won't work in IE and Edge.

Comment: Thank you. I am not very  concerned about IE or Edge users. However is there a way to implement this in these browsers?

Comment: I don't think so, as they don't support transform-origin in SVG at all: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

An example of animation directly in the SVG file without CSS

```css
svg {
  height: 178px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;"
  xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="sharp-grp" transform="translate(50, 50) rotate(0) scale(0.8, 0.8)">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path fill="#746DF7"
          d="M493.815,70.629c-11.001-1.003-20.73,7.102-21.733,18.102l-2.65,
          29.069C424.473,47.194,346.429,0,256,0C158.719,0,72.988,55.522,
          30.43,138.854c-5.024,9.837-1.122,21.884,8.715,26.908c9.839,5.024,
          21.884,1.123,26.908-8.715C102.07,86.523,174.397,40,256,40c74.377,0,
          141.499,38.731,179.953,99.408l-28.517-20.367c-8.989-6.419-21.48
          -4.337-27.899,4.651c-6.419,8.989-4.337,21.479,4.651,27.899l86.475,
          61.761c12.674,9.035,30.155,0.764,31.541-14.459l9.711-106.53
          C512.919,81.362,504.815,71.632,493.815,70.629z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <g>
        <path fill="#746DF7"
          d="M472.855,346.238c-9.838-5.023-21.884-1.122-26.908,8.715C409.93,
          425.477,337.603,472,256,472c-74.377,0-141.499-38.731-179.953-99.408
          l28.517,20.367c8.989,6.419,21.479,4.337,27.899-4.651c6.419-8.989,
          4.337-21.479-4.651-27.899l-86.475-61.761c-12.519-8.944-30.141-0.921
          -31.541,14.459l-9.711,106.53c-1.003,11,7.102,20.73,18.101,21.733
          c11.014,1.001,20.731-7.112,21.733-18.102l2.65-29.069C87.527,
          464.806,165.571,512,256,512c97.281,0,183.012-55.522,225.57-138.854
          C486.594,363.309,482.692,351.262,472.855,346.238z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
  <animateTransform xlink:href="#sharp-grp" attributeType="xml"
     attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 256 256"
     to="360 256 256" dur="2s" additive="sum" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</svg>
```

You can change the animation config at

```
<animateTransform xlink:href="#sharp-group" attributeType="xml"
  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 256 256" to="360 256 256"
  dur="2s" additive="sum" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

For references:
https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/